# cakePHP Combobox looses selection on pagination

Tags: cakephp, combobox, pagination

this is my first page I create with cakePHP and I have the following problem/scenario:

I'm creating a highscore-page using different models as the given databaes provides the information in different tables. I'm using pagination and a form with two comboboxes to allow the selection of special attributes. To set the filter-conditions I'm using the beforeFilter()-function and set the conditions (and joins) dynamically. All the conditions are also stored in the session because of keeping them for the pagination. This alls works fine.

My problem is now the following: When I submit the form the result ist correct and the comboboxes **are preselected** with the options I just have chosen. When I now switch to page2/3/... the comboboxes are **loose there selections** and are on their empty-option.

How can I keep the selection through the pagination?

My controller beforeFilter()-function

```
// Highscorefilter
public function beforeFilter()
{
  parent::beforeFilter();

  // Dropdown für Rassen
  $this->set('racelist', $this->Race->getRaceList());

  // Dropdown für Galaxien
  $this->set('galaxylist', $this->Galaxy->getGalaxyList());


  // Initialisierung
  $filter_conditions = array();
  $joins = array();
  $filter = FALSE;

  if($this->request->is('post'))
  {

    // Um die Filter richtig zu erkennen brauchen wir den Modelnamen :/
    switch($this->action)
    {
      case "imperium":
        $model = "HighscoreImperiumUser";
        break;
      case "quest":
        $model = "HighscoreQuestUser";
        break;
      case "war":
        $model = "HighscoreWarUser";
        break;
      case "trade":
        $model = "HighscoreTradeUser";
        break;        
      case "overall":
      default:
        $model = "HighscoreOverallUser";
        break;
    }    

    // Filter auslesen und setzen

    $data = $this->request->data;

    if(isset($data[$model]['race_id']) && !empty($data[$model]['race_id']))
    {
      // WHERE-Bedingung race_id setzen
      $tmpstr = sprintf("%s.race_id", $model);
      $filter_conditions[$tmpstr] = $data[$model]['race_id'];

      // Joins setzten wir in diesem Fall auf ein leeres array. Das wird ggf. nachher überschrieben
      $joins = array();
    }

    if(isset($data[$model]['gala']) && !empty($data[$model]['gala']))
    {
      // WHERE-Bedingung gala setzen
      $tmpstr = sprintf("ug.gala", $model);
      $filter_conditions[$tmpstr] = $data[$model]['gala'];        

      // WHERE-Bedingung für Join bauen und Join konstruieren
      $tmpstr = sprintf("ug.userid = %s.id", $model);
      $join = array( 'alias' => 'ug',
                     'table' => 'user_gala',
                     'type' => 'INNER',
                     'conditions' => $tmpstr);
      $joins[] = $join;

    }

    // Filterinformationen für Seitenwechsel in Session schreiben
    $this->Session->delete('_indexConditions');
    $this->Session->delete('_indexJoins');
    $this->Session->write('_indexConditions', $filter_conditions);
    $this->Session->write('_indexJoins', $joins);

    $filter = TRUE;

  }
  else if(!empty($this->request->params['named']['page']))
  { // Filterinformationen aus der Session holen
    $filter_conditions = (array)$this->Session->read('_indexConditions');
    $joins = (array)$this->Session->read('_indexJoins');

    $filter = TRUE;
  }

  if($filter)
  {      
    // set filter conditions of each pagination model
    $this->paginate = Hash::insert($this->paginate, '{s}.conditions', $filter_conditions);
    $this->paginate = Hash::insert($this->paginate, '{s}.joins', $joins);           
  }
}
```

One of the "real"-controller-function (they are all straith-forwand, just using the different models)

```
// Overall (Default) Highscore
public function overall()
{
  // Paginate der Highscore
  $highscoreusers = $this->paginate('HighscoreOverallUser');
  $this->set('highscoreusers', $highscoreusers);

  // Variablen für View setzen
  $this->set('model', 'HighscoreOverallUser');
  $this->set('title', __d('highscore', 'Overall score'));

  // Index-View benutzen
  $this->render('index');
}
```

My view-Form

```
  = $this->Form->create($model, array('type' => 'post', 'url' => array('action' => $this->request['action'], 'controller' => $this->request['controller'])))
  %table
    %tr
      %td{:width => "200px"}
        = $this->Form->label('race_id', __d('highscore', 'Only show race:'))
      %td{:width => "100px"}
        = $this->Form->select('race_id', $racelist, array('legend' => false, 'class' => 'select', 'empty' => __d('highscore', 'All races') ))
      %td{:width => "200px"}
        = $this->Form->label('gala', __d('highscore', 'Only show players in galaxy:'))
      %td{:width => "100px"}
        = $this->Form->select('gala', $galaxylist, array('legend' => false, 'class' => 'select', 'empty' => __d('highscore', 'All galaxies') ))

  = $this->Form->end(__d('highscore', 'Activate filter'))
```

Comment: Please include your code for the actual combo box in question.

Comment: added the whole form, including the two used combo boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the data-values (e.g. "data[HighscoreOverallUser][race_id]") of cakePHP are not set after switching the page with paginator.

So they have to be set manually. The following code worked for me. Sure you have to be careful not to override set data, but as far as I can say now after using the paginator the data is always not set

```
if(!$this->data->HighscoreOverallUser)
{
  $data['HighscoreOverallUser']['race_id'] = $filter_conditions['HighscoreOverallUser.race_id'];
  $this->data = $data;
}
```